# Choosing dpi to export images from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export

I need to export images from ArcMap to embed them in a pdf via LaTeX. Some images should fit a whole page, while others should cover an area equal to approximately 1/4 of the paper page.

If I want to export them with an .eps format, what is the dpi I should give them?

Comment: Whatever DPI (and any other export settings) look best to you when you export your image.  What is the page size you are putting the images on?  There are probably some guides (from print publishers) about what settings to use for different page sizes

Comment: See [I need to print an image a certain size. What dimensions and resolutions should I use?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should)

Comment: like @Midavalo linked too...it depends on what the end user wants. What is the purpose of the export? There is a difference between creating an image for screen use vs a print...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as alluded to via this linked question [I need to print an image a certain size. What dimensions and resolutions should I use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should)

It depends on what the final use of the images is.

Answer (score 0):

For print on demand 300dpi is considered adequate for graphics, except when it was expanded upward from a lower raster dpi resolution.  A submittal with images less than 300dpi is rejected by CreateSpace's automated error detection during pdf-book submittals, for example.  So anything below 300dpi is considered visibly less sharp by the book industry.

If you know specific images print size are going to be reduced by half (so that four can be fitted on a single page) then 150dpi for the originals should be a minimum adequate resolution, given the 300dpi standard, and given that you only reduce the dimension, and not the number of pixels. If you choose 150dpi you should double check the method you use to reduce the print size of any graphics so that the final graphics come out to at least 300dpi.

I do hear of folks using 600dpi, because they can, but I can't visually see the difference between 300dpi and 600dpi myself.  [note that ***.eps*** is a vector graphic format that may also contain raster.]